# attach a polygon to show tf in rviz

Tags: ros, footprint, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

I want to show a footprint of my robot in rviz. I have my tf like /laser, /base_link, /odom and /map in rviz and i can see them and track my robot movement. But i want to attach a polygon to my tf. Should i use a urdf or it is really more simpler than this????

thanks:)))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198949/attach-a-polygon-to-show-tf-in-rviz/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

simple way is to publish a [marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) in `/base_link` frame,  Marker of  cube type with length,width and height as size of your robot looks fine.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-12-06**:
Do you know a good tutorial on this?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-06**:
This tutorial helps [rviz markers :Sending Basic Shapes](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes#Sending_Markers)